# CakePhp3 Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I want to access image file in this folder by local.myproject/assets/logo.jpg
Note that /img/ folder is not in the URL

```
|-webroot
    |-js
    |-img
       |-assets
           |-logo.jpg
```

How can i configure this on my htaccess
currently my .httacess under webroot is like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ img/assets/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is not working.

Comment: Shouln't it be `RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ img/assets/rainbow/$1 [R=301,L]` ?

Comment: Still not working with "RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ img/assets/rainbow/$1 [R=301,L]"

Comment: `rainbow` does not exits. What should happen after redirection? `index.php` should handle the request? Your question is unclear. Please exactly describe the expected behaviour.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone sorry that typo error the rainbow. I just want only to bind /img/assets/logo.jpg to /img/logo.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following rule :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^assets(.*)$ /img/assets$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```